# Winforms: How to Set Label Text on First Form When Opening a Second

Tags: c#, winforms

In my windows forms application, I close one form and open another like this:

```
MyApp.MySecondForm frmInst = new MyApp.MySecondForm();
frmInst.Show();
this.Hide();
```

But before I open like this, I set label text in my first form because I want to inform the user that second form is loading.

Imagine second form's loading takes 10 seconds, when I press the button in order to open the second button, the label text doesn't get changed until the second form gets open. When I close the second form, I recall the first form and see that the text has changed.

Which way should I follow to set label text right after user clicks a button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should perform that loading in a background thread.

Comment: on the first or second form? first form, it caused an error.

Comment: have you tried calling Refresh() before showing the second form? Just before frmInst.Show()

Comment: @SLaks Creating forms on a background thread is a very bad idea. Only the actual process that takes so long could be useful to run on a background thread, but the creation of the controls/forms themselves must be done on the UI thread.

Comment: @Forte L. shame on me... I always thought I need to make a thread on background. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `Refresh()` method before `frmInst.Show()`. Because the graphics will not refresh until the method is finished executing, unless you do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Are you firing that 10 second process asynchronously?

If not, that's what's causing the delay. It getting the information (10 seconds), then updating the GUI thread.

Try using a BackgroundWorker:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: Thanks, it binds data from a web function to grid on form_Load event. I'm not looking at the BW. I should use it on the first form, right?

Comment: If the grid is on the first form, then yes, fire it from the first form.

Comment: Grid is on the second form. I'm now solving with Refresh() but I'll take a look at BW, it seems useful when I try to do more. Thanks.